# C++ How to access an object of another class?

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance

I want to have 1 class that holds all objects to my other classes.
So for example: If player class want a member of enemy class, I want to access the enemy class using that 1 class.

An example:

```
class objectHolder{
public:
    enemyClass enemy;
};

class enemyClass{
public:
    void member();
};

class player{
public:
    objectHolder oh;
    oh.enemy.member(); //I KNOW THIS IS ILLEGAL BUT I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS
};
```

I know the code is incorrect and does not compile well, but I hope you get the idea. Does anyone know how to actually do this? Because I actually need 1 class that all classes can access. Every class can call getters and setters and stuff from other classes by using that 1 big class.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: Funny that someone dislikes my question without a reason or even knowing how to do this. If you don't know the answer than go away?

Comment: it's long time to write c++ code, but where did you instantiate the oh object (= new objectHolder), also, the same case for enemy.  Moreover, it is legal to call oh.enemy.member() as the memeber is public and enemy is public..

Comment: I'm just very confused on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: "1 class that holds all objects". It's called the "god pattern" and generally causes more problems than it solves. (IOW, don't feel bad. You're by far not the first person to come up with the idea. )

Comment: I was trying to make 1 class, all other classes can access(for getters and setters from other classes). So that classes can access each others getters/setters etc. But to make many objects every class is not efficient. So I wanted to use 1 class that settles that.

Comment: *"If you don't know the answer than go away?"* - SO is not an answer service but an attempt at building up a knowledge base. Closing unproductive questions with no imaginable future use is thus **encouraged**. Not saying that this applies to your case, but your take on this (don't know answer -> go away) is clearly wrong.

Comment: -Christian Hackl Yes, but it is annoying when someone dislikes your question without giving a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oh.enemy.member();` is a perfectly legal C++ statement since all members involved have `public` access.  Where you've put it makes no sense however since statements can only appear in a function body.

Comment: So object.object.member() is legal? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: It is legal in a method, not in the class definition.

Comment: Thanks! I was just misunderstanding but now all of my problems are solved, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can not call function in class body ... try this code may useful

```
 class enemyClass{
 public:
void member(){std::cout<<"Test";}
 };
class objectHolder{ 
public:
enemyClass enemy;
enemyClass getEnemy(){return enemy;}
};

class player{
public:
objectHolder oh;
void getresult(){oh.getob().member();}
};
 int main()
{
player p;
 p.getresult();
 }
```

Comment: yes, I did read it. as I think I used the same idea for access. logically what did you mention is correct but the position of your statement  I don't think in the right place @HugoCornel

Comment: Maybe It is my English that makes it unclear. My English is sh*t.

Comment: Sorry , for my misunderstanding. I haven't read the question carefully.

Comment: @0xFFFFFF Typo? It should be `oh.getEnemy().member();` not `oh.getob().member();`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Make a singleton

2) Initialize it & include all objects you want to hold.

3) Access the singleton instance from anywhere you please.

4) Realize that this is a horrible way to structure your program.